# How can I remove the mapEntry with the value is null and correct the type?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

For the case of nullable variable, I can use `whereType` to remove the null value in a list:

```
List<String?> myList = [null, '123'];
List<String> updatedList = List.from(myList.whereType<String>());
print(updatedList);

// get [123]
```

But when it comes to Map, it cannot work as expected:

```
Map<String, String?> myMap = {'a':'123', 'b': null};
Map<String, String> updatedMap = Map.fromEntries(myMap.entries.whereType<MapEntry<String,String>>());
print(updatedMap);

// get {}
```

I can only think of a workaround method by wrapping it with another function with a for-loop, adding the result and return. It does not sound elegant at all. Can someone suggest how to handle th case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Remove null key pair

```dart
 myMap.removeWhere((key, value) => value == null);
```

#### Create Map from map

```dart
Map<String, String> updatedMap = Map.from(myMap);
```

More about [`Map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.0/dart-core/Map-class.html).

Comment: Thanks, I think this one is the closet one to my best answer. I am now using `final updatedMap = Map<String, String>.from(myMap..removeWhere((key, value) => value == null));`  The dart implicitly type casting is more difficult than it looks.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, using **where** to filter null and **map** to convert `<String, String?>` to `<String, String>`.

ps: you can't use `as ...<String, String>` that why need **map**.

```dart
void main() {
  Map<String, String?> myMap = {'a':'123', 'b': null};
  // Map<String, String> updatedMap = Map.fromEntries(myMap.entries.whereType<MapEntry<String,String>>());
  Map<String, String> updatedMap = Map.fromEntries(myMap.entries.where((e) => e.value != null).map((e) => MapEntry(e.key, e.value!)));
  print(updatedMap);
  print(updatedMap.runtimeType);
  
  // result
  // {a: 123}
  // JsLinkedHashMap<String, String>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  var myMap = {'a':'123', 'b': null};
  print(myMap);
  myMap.removeWhere((key, value) => value == null);
  print(myMap);
}
```

Output:

```
{a: 123, b: null}
{a: 123}
```

Comment: But it not change the `Map` type, it still `<String, String?>`